# Symfony Mailer: Expected response code "250" but got empty code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, symfony-mailer

We started getting error `Expected response code "250" but got empty code.` when sending emails via Symfony Mailer on Laravel 10 and Mailchimp.

There are lots of similar questions and all of them were related to invalid credentials/not refreshed configs/etc. E.g. something was wrong with the setup.

In our case it is different.

Emails are sent by Laravel queue workers with retries. And when this error happens the email *might* be resent successfully on retry by the same worker on the same server.

So it is **not** a config issue.

This is how successful retry looks in logs:
[image]

But what else could cause the same error?

P.S. Error began after upgrade from Laravel 8.XX to Laravel 10.

Comment: Take a look at the Laravel upgrade guides: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade and see if there's anything in there about Mailing. Actually, found something (possibly relevant): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer; when upgrading from `8.x` to `9.x`, looks like a lot around the Mail logic has changed. See if that documentation can shed any light on your situation.

Comment: Yes, there was an issue with `setBody` which was used in our emails, switched to `html` method to fix that, and that was mentioned in the quide. Other than that it was fine

Comment: Excellent; typically people don't follow the upgrade guide and often miss things like that  glad to hear you went through the process and caught that already.

Comment: Hm, maybe this is the reason? "It is no longer possible to force a transport reconnection (for example when the mailer is running via a daemon process). Instead, Symfony Mailer will attempt to reconnect to the transport automatically and throw an exception if the reconnection fails."